# NSPredicate array contains question

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, search, nspredicate, contains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching/Filtering a custom class array with a NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207050/searching-filtering-a-custom-class-array-with-a-nspredicate)

I have a array that contains objects of a custom class, and I would like to filter the array based on if one of the classes attributes contains a custom string. I have a method that is passed the attribute that I want to be searched (column) and the string that it will search for (searchString). Here is the code I have:

```
NSPredicate *query = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains %@", column,      searchString];
NSMutableArray *temp = [displayProviders mutableCopy];
[displayProviders release];
displayProviders = [[temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:query] mutableCopy];
[temp release];
```

For some reason, this always returns an empty array. Three of the four columns are ints or doubles, so I could add an if statment to convert searchString to a number, if needed. However, even when searching the attribute that is a string, and should have some rows that contain the string searchString, an empty array is returned.

Am I using "contains" incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

For searching strings in a predicate, i've found that wrapping single quotation marks around what I am searching for works best and using `contains[cd]` rather than `contains` like below (the [cd] bit specifies a case & diacritic insensitive search):

```
NSPredicate *query = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ contains[cd] '%@'", column, searchString];
```

For searching a column with Integers, using double equals should work fine too:

```
NSPredicate *query = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", column, searchString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your predicate should be `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"column contains %@", searchString]`

The way it is right now, your predicate becomes `""column" contains "string""`, which always evaluates to false.

Using `contains[cd]` may also be a good idea depending on your situation.